# installing open edx on Ubuntu 14.04.1

Tags: vagrant, ubuntu-14.04, virtualization, openedx

i tried to install Open edX Fullstack on my Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS

i followed the installation documentation

```
mkdir fullstack
cd fullstack
curl -L https://raw.githubusercontent.com/edx/configuration/master/vagrant/release/fullstack/Vagrantfile > Vagrantfile
vagrant plugin install vagrant-hostsupdater
vagrant up
```

but after that, when i opened virtualbox

and vagrant keep showing

```
default: Error: Connection timeout. Retrying...

==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
    default: Adapter 2: hostonly
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 22 => 2222 (adapter 1)
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    default: SSH username: vagrant
    default: SSH auth method: private key
    default: Error: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    default: Error: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    default: Error: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    default: Error: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    default: Error: Connection timeout. Retrying...
```

i added this code to Vagrantfile to show up the window fullstack virtual machine

```
config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
  vb.gui = true
end
```

and i entered manually to Ubuntu [hitting the Enter Key]

but, after a moment i get a black windows with a blinking cursor on it !

and still getting

```
default: Error: Connection timeout. Retrying...
```

in the terminal !

PS: 
My computer doesn't support virtualization Technology

(i tried the same steps on Windows 8.1, but i get the same Error)

PC Info:

Processor: Pentium(R) Dual-Core CPU T4300 @ 2.10GHz 2.10Ghz

RAM : 4 GB

Comment: You seem to have answered yourself, "My computer doesn't support virtual technology", if this is true you cannot install a virtual machine. Did you google the error?

Comment: yah ! i google it, then if i don't have virtualization technology i cannot install a virtual machine ?

Comment: If your computer specifically doesn't support virtual technology than you cannot host virtual machines. Even if it did I don't think you'd have enough memory to run much more than the operating systems themselves. Unless someone with more experience has something to say.

Comment: ok, thank you !
(in the system requirement, they said "Minimum 2GB of memory, 4GB recommended for production servers")

Comment: That's probably free memory. Win7 itself runs on 1gig of memory and 8.1 2gigs. Hosting a virtual machine would add that again leaving you with whatever is left over.

Comment: Also to ensure your VMs have enough memory, when you get a machine that supports such an action you can use msconfig to manage boot settings and how much memory/cpu resources the native OS consumes. You can use this to throttle the native OS not make it use less than it needs.

Comment: yah, maybe you are right, the default setting of the virtual machine have 4096 Mb on Base memory, and 2 processors (i reconfigured it to 1960 in Base RAM and 1 processor)
thanks a lot for your reply !

Comment: Sure thing. FYI for future questions like this, involving the installation and use of VM, you might be better off taking it to Super User. While I'm sure most people working in the developing field know how to install and use VMs it's not really on-topic for Stack Overflow unless it is a programming related question.

Answer (score 0):

This error

```
default: Error: Connection timeout. Retrying...
```

Cause of your internet connection.

You can't install Open Edx in Ubuntu 14.04 at this time, isn't supported yer but if you want to do research on it there's small discussion about installing open edx on Ubuntu 14.04 here https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/edx-code/d0gc1lhQ7-Q

Advice from me is please use Ubuntu 12.04 for best support.

Thanks,